# Colorbox empty on iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, colorbox

I am building social login for my website. The approach is to click a "Login with Facebook" button, which opens a popup. The popup authenticates the user at Facebook and when done, it opens a colorbox modal on the parent page through a javascript function which is one hte parent:

```
<script>
function update_modal(update_href){
  $('.loginmodal').colorbox({open: true, href: update_href});
}
</script>
```

On the popup I call

```
window.opener.update_modal(URL);
```

On a regular desktop it works great. But on an iPad the modal opens empty.

Any one worked with Colorbox and experienced problems of this type?

Comment: Update to this issue. Now I have tried to debug the safari browser on my iPad using my Mac book and safari developer tools. Actually, I can see the html code is fully correct, but is not rendered to the screen. Only a blank modal.

So now I wonder if this is a general issue with Colorbox and iPad - or if i am missing some sort of setting when making the call to the colorbox...

Comment: Another comment on this. The issue is only on IOS6. On IOS7 it works fine.